# Integrating Facebook Docset with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, appledoc

So I downloaded the latest 3.1 Facebook iOS sdk and under the scripts I found a build_documentation.sh which I ran. It completed and generated a com.facebook.Facebook-SDK-3_0-for-iOS.docset file. I am trying to get it to integrate nicely with XCode. I know that apple docs can create documentation that shows up in the quick help panel. My own custom documentation works great.

Does anyone know what I have to do to get the same kind of documentation integration with Facebook?

---

EDIT:
I tried adding the docset to the corresponding folder according to the instructions [here](http://markthomas.info/blog/?p=189)
and restarted Xcode but it didn't work

Comment: copying the docset to  ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets works here. Maybe check in the Console.app for any hint?

Comment: @Pfitz wasn't able to figure out anything from Console.app but Dash.app did tell me that the Facebook SDK Documentation is missing an index. I don't know if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install the SDK from the package you don't have to generate the docset yourself.

- Go to https://developers.facebook.com/ios
- Click on the Download SDK button

Comment: Perfect! This worked. Although I would have liked to know exactly how the installation worked, whatever gets the job done!

Comment: @Endama Why does it work by installing the Facebook Framework directly from the .pkg?
It moves it to **/Library/...**, **not** to ~/Library/... (**notice the "~" which stands for your users dir**)

Comment: I am really not sure... I think I might have configured Appledocs to pull from /Library?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Facebook Documentation **working** with the following:

- Build the Facebook Documentation with the provided shell scripts
- Move the .docset to /Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets

**If it doesn't work, you may have to check, if you moved the docset to *~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets*. This is sometimes WRONG**

Why does it work by installing the Facebook Framework directly from the .pkg?
**It moves it to /Library/..., not to ~/Library/...**